# HttpStatusCodeResult message encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, character-encoding, http-status-codes

I need to return a HttpStatusCodeResult object with description, which contains special (diacritics) characters. I don't know how to set proper encoding.

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Zażółć gęsią jaźń.");
```

Should return:

> Zażółć gęsią jaźń.

but I get:

> Za¿ó³æ gêsi¹ jañ.

I was trying with `Response.Charset = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.WebName;` etc. but still nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't get "Za¿ó³æ gêsi¹ jañ." anywhere.

But you can't get "Zażółć gęsią jaźń." in the HTTP status line reason phrase because it only supports the ASCII character set and encoding [[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-22) ]. (HTTP header fields do have a mechanism for %-encoding, etc., but not the status line.)

So, you could leave the reason phrase out and put the message in the body:

```
Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Content("Zażółć gęsią jaźń. And, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ");
```

Use whatever content you want, including HTML. But, the web browser that receives this might override the content if it's [not long enough](https://perishablepress.com/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/) to seem useful and modern. You should also consider if the web server is configured to replace error pages. This could help:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for you support. After replacing a `HttpStatusCodeResult` object with a `Content()`, encoding is ok and a diacritics characters displays in a right way.

Comment: I have a similar scenario, and strangely enough, on local IIS I receive messages with special characters, but on the Azure environment they are ASCII encoded. Maybe a latest .NET version finally allows for that to be configured?